# D3 Bubble plot working on local server but NOT on http server

Tags: javascript, d3.js, uikit, visualization

I've adjusted this code https://vallandingham.me/bubble_charts_in_js.html by Jim Vallandingham using my own data.

It is working fine when I test and run it on a local server but the graph is NOT visible when I place it into a uikit framework (there are no other d3 files in it - just jQuery) and transfer it over to my own server

Here's the uikit framework I'm using:

```
<div class="container uk-container-center uk-hidden-medium uk-hidden-small" style="padding-top">  

    <div id="toolbar" class="uk-container uk-container-center uk-text-center" style="padding-top:3em">
            <div>
                    <a href="#/all" id="all" class="button active">All Data</a>
                    <a href="#/year" id="year" class="button">Date of data</a>
            </div>
                            
                <div id="vis"></div>
    </div>
```

But for the sake of space I've put all the code on this [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v931c0km/1/)

Any thoughts, most most welcome!

Comment: you have an error in your js fiddle `Uncaught ReferenceError: floatingTooltip is not defined`

Comment: Thanks @Faraz A. I've updated the jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/L6c4hfw9/) with the Tooltip js in script on the html. Any thought on why this is working on my local server and not http?

Answer (score -1):

In your fiddle, the d3 script import's path is relative:

```
<script src="js/d3.js"></script>
```

You might want to use it from the CDN directly:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I had thought that but have trying it both in the head and the bottom of the document - still no joy @Hugo Elhaj-Lahsen